# Использование оператора '&'

Tags: java

В `HashMap` есть метод

```
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict) { ...}
```

В котором выполняется проверка на уникальность ключа.
Для определения уникальности используется сравнение чисел оператором `&`. Соответственно вопрос:

Что именно выполняет оператор `&` между двумя числами?

```
12 & 0 //0
12 & 5 //4
12 & 12 //12
12 & 150 //4
15 & 67888795; //11
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Это побитовый оператор AND

```
  00101010  42
& 00001111  15
--------------
  00001010  10
```

Два числа представляются в двоичном виде. Затем оператором `&` сравниваются каждый бит двух чисел. Как работает оператор AND: если оба числа равны 1, то результат 1, если только один равен единице или оба нуля, то результат 0. Затем обратно из двоичного вида преобразуем в десятичный и получается обычное число.

Answer (score 8):

Это операция побитового "И".

Из [вики](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%91%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8#.D0.9F.D0.BE.D0.B1.D0.B8.D1.82.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BE.D0.B5_.D0.98_.28AND.29):

> Побитовое И — это бинарная операция, действие которой эквивалентно применению логического И к каждой паре битов, которые стоят на одинаковых позициях в двоичных представлениях операндов. Другими словами, если оба соответствующих бита операндов равны 1, результирующий двоичный разряд равен 1; если же хотя бы один бит из пары равен 0, результирующий двоичный разряд равен 0.

Comment: 15 и 67888795 это:
1111 и 100000010111110011010011011

И как получается число 11?

Comment: перед 1111 происходит выравнивание нулями, от данной операции остаётся 1011 что является 11 в десятичной